# Maximal sub-inverse semigroups of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $M_n(F_p)$

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

An inverse semigroup $S$ is a semigroup in which every element $x \in S$ has a unique inverse $y \in S$ such that $x = xyx$ and $y = yxy$. Are there some references characterizing the maximal sub-inverse-semigroups of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $M_n(F_p)$? Here $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the monoid of all $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and $M_n(F_p)$ is the monoid of all $n \times n$ matrices over the $p$-element field $F_p$. Thank you very much.

Comment: The question you ask is natural, but does the question come from some other problem?

Comment: There has been studied a lot of things like maximal subsemigroups of various kind for semigroups of linear mappings on vector spaces by former students of Olexandr Ganyushkin -- Vasyl Pyekhterev, Ganna Kudryavtseva

Comment: What i guess is still unclassified and quite difficult problem is: what are the maximal inverse subsemigroups in the transformation monoid $T_n$. I suspect for the linear case it is even tougher

Comment: You might look at L. B. Shneperman. On maximal compact subsemigroups of the endomorphism semigroup of an n-dimensional
complex vector space. Semigroup Forum, 47(2):196–208, 1993.  Here maximal compact inverse semigroups are studied.

Comment: Also, Nemyrovska used to do thing like maximal subsemigroups of various transformation semigroups

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this article will be useful for you:

Zhu Yong Wen, Inverse Semigroups of Matrices. Journal of Mathematical Research & Exposition, Aug., 2008, Vol. 28, No. 3, pp. 549–557.